# what does a "RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'." error mean?

Tags: python, flask, pyppeteer

So I've been trying to make a simple bitcoin price checker with pyppeteer. It's working like a charm but whenever I try to implement it to flask I get a runtime error.

Essentially, I want to build a web api call that whenever I click a button it calls the webscraper file.

If somebody could help guide me, that would greatly appreciated!

**Flask Server**

```
import webscraper
import asyncio

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title="Home")

@app.route('/api/scrape', methods=['POST'])
def scrape():
    webscraper.crypto_price('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    app.run()
```

**Pyppeteer File**

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import browser, launch

def write_to_file(file, text):
    f = open(file, 'w')
    f.write(text)
    f.close

def crypto_price(link):
    async def main():
        browser = await launch()
        page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setViewport({'width': 1920, 'height': 1080})

        await page.goto(link, {'waitUntil': 'networkidle2'})
        data = await page.evaluate('''()=> {
            return {
                price: document.querySelector('#__next > div > div.main-content > div.sc-57oli2-0.dEqHl.cmc-body-wrapper > div > div.sc-16r8icm-0.hNsOU.container > div.sc-16r8icm-0.kXPxnI.container___lbFzk > div.sc-16r8icm-0.kXPxnI.priceSection___3kA4m > div.sc-16r8icm-0.kXPxnI.priceTitle___1cXUG > div').innerText
            }
        }''')

        await browser.close()

        write_to_file('./webscrape_result.txt', data['price'])

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**Error**

```
[2021-05-14 09:30:15,007] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/scrape [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request     
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\Python Web Scraper\server.py", line 14, in scrape
    webscraper.crypto_price('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/')
  File "C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\Python Web Scraper\webscraper.py", line 26, in crypto_price
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to run `asyncio.get_event_loop()` in some thread other than the main thread - however, asyncio only generates an event loop for the main thread.

Instead use `new_event_loop`:

```
asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```